# Swift - Automatically trigger functions at particular times

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Swift as a programming language and Firebase for my backend. My use case is about creating an event (a tournament) which has different rounds (RoundOf16, Quarter-Finale, Semi-Finale etc.)

Whenever a new rounds starts and finishes, I want to send out notifications to the participants. It would be easy to do that by using local notifications.

However, additionally to sending the notifications, I also want to trigger a function to check if a participant can make it to the next round (if a round is finished) or if the event has even enough participants to start.

How can I do that? Is there a client-side way to achieve this or can it only be done server-side? The functions would need to run completely in the background as it is the case that you close the app, even though the round is still active.

We have to consider that multiple tournaments are going to be created. This means, for each tournament, we have couple of rounds with a beginning and ending date.

What would be the most elegant way? Having one function where I pass the *tournamentId* so based on that, I can check who won the round? But wouldn't I overwrite the function to be triggered every time then?

Comment: Do you actually want to send notifications? Or is the goal to have anyone that's playing know a round started or finished while they are in game? If it's the later simply having your app observe (listen) to a certain node/collection in Firebase would suffice, after all, Firebase is an event driven platform and that would be an event. Please update your question with which database you are using - either the Realtime Database or Firestore.

Comment: Hello @Jay, thanks for the reply. I am using FireStore. Using an observer is a good hint. If the ending time/date of a round is reached, there should be a logic to identify the winner of the round. From my point of view, doesn't it make sense to do that server-side?

Comment: Three's really no way for us to know what the "right" way to do it is without understanding the entire use case. My initial thought would be to do it client side but that may not be the best for your situation.